# How can I get Unity Container to cascade the registration name down the chain?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Consider the following:

```
public class MyService : IService {
  public MyService(IDbSession session) {}
}


// Service used both by controller and background work.
container.RegisterType<IService, MyService>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

// Database session when used from a controller
container.RegisterType<IDbSession, DbSession>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
// Database session as used when doing background work
container.RegisterType<IDbSession, DbSession>("BackgroundWork", new TransientLifetimeManager());



// At run-time I expect the named resolution to be "cascading" down to the IDbSession named registration.
container.Resolve<IService>("BackgroundWork");
```

I'd like to resolve the `IDbSession` with the "BackgroundWork" name, since the `IService` is being resolved with that name.

Unity does not do this unless I manually specify the constructor parameters in an `InjectionConstructor`, which is not that intuitive. I'd have to keep that updated as the signature of my service changes.

How can I do this in the least painless way?

The idea is that when doing background work, my Db session must be managed by the class doing the background work, not the request.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it please.

Comment: @jlvaquero updated my question to better reflect the scenario, please notice the single registration of IService with a transient lifetime manager.

Comment: Much better. The use of child containers is still my answer. ;)

Comment: @jlvaquero yes, and thats what I am using now. However, notice how IService is only registered in the parent container, and since MyService depends on IDbSession, somehow the one registered in the parent container is injected. But if I register MyService in the child container, then it works.

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong. Check the last version of my answer. I didn't register IService in child and when child resolve IService I get a new DbSession instance not the DbSession created by the parent.

Comment: @jlvaquero My scenario is a bit more complex (I was mapping an IEnumerable<ISomeThing> to ISomeThing[], and if I did not include that mapping in the child container, the `ISomeThing`s from the parent container were used when the IEnumerable was injected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use child container.

```
 IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
 container.RegisterType<IService, MyService>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
 container.RegisterType<IDbSession, DBSession>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

 IUnityContainer childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
 childContainer.RegisterType<IDbSession, DBSession>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

 IService parentService = container.Resolve<IService>();
 IService parentService2 = container.Resolve<IService>();
 IService childService = childContainer.Resolve<IService>();
IService childService2 = childContainer.Resolve<IService>();
```

Inmed Window:

```
?parentService.GetHashCode()
45653674
?parentService2.GetHashCode()
41149443
//one service instance per resolve
?parentService.session.GetHashCode()
39785641
?parentService2.session.GetHashCode()
39785641
//same DBSesion in every service resolved per HTTP request
?childService.GetHashCode()
45523402
?childService.session.GetHashCode()
35287174
//new Service and DbSession per resolve
?childService2.GetHashCode()
44419000
?childService2.session.GetHashCode()
52697953
```

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea! I'd have to drag around a reference to the child container, but I think I can code my way out of that with a factory-like class. Thanks!

Comment: so I do have to register the entire chain again, in order for it to work, right?

Comment: If the entire chain is different yes. Child containers inhertis registered types from parent. You have just to override the differences in the child config to match desired config.

Comment: Yes, but I've found that if I do not register `IService`, and I use the child container to resolve `IService`, then the `IDbSession` registered from the parent container is used, so it did not work until I registered the entire chain in the child container again, even with the same config. Is this normal?

Comment: If the IService is in PerRequestLifetimeManager every resolve in the same HTTP request brings you back the first MyService created for the first resolve. The container just store a pointer to IService and returns it. If IService already has a reference to IDbSession, resolving from child doesn't create a new IDbSession even if you had different config about IDbSession in child because child just get the pointer of IService created and return it.

Comment: Yes, I understand - I just had an issue where I didnt register a type in the child container, despite it being Transient, and all its dependencies would come from the parent container. It's as if when I resolve a type from the child container, and any dependencies in the chain is not registered in the child container, then that type's dependencies will also come from the parent container, as if it would use the parent container to resolve the remaining dependencies in that types graph. Does this make just a little sense? Sorry for the confusion. :P

Comment: Yes, has sense. It is expected behaviour. The problem with child containers is that requires very careful planning and know how because life time managers in child and in parents. Even the order of resolving from child or parent can mean a difference in some circumstances.

Comment: Okay, so I do have to register the entire chain again in order for the dependencies to propagate properly. Thanks. :)